# What hash GCP uses to derive the ID of a service account's uploaded public key?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hash, service-accounts

Im trying to find how GCP resolves/derives the ID of a public key when uploaded to a service-account.

So far, is not a random ID because every time I upload the same key, I get the same ID.
In this question https://serverfault.com/questions/1030519/google-cloud-how-to-determine-key-id-from-p12, the accepted answer says that the ID is the SHA1 fingerprint of the certificate, however, so far my fingerprint does not match what GCP is displaying.

So, I generated a certificate using the following command:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 \
    -keyout ./private_key.pem \
    -out ./public_key.pem \
    -subj "/CN=unused"
```

And the resulting public key is this one:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The sha1 fingerprint of the key is:

```
SHA1 Fingerprint=3F:82:28:D5:CD:25:D8:43:0C:7A:5D:7D:00:F6:32:DC:0A:8F:71:29
```

When I upload this public key to a GCP service account (using the console, as my users would do) I get the following ID:

```
253b469718cfe08e09a30bd55e09f16f68a0fe97
```

When I decode that string (Key ID) from base64 I get:

```
db:9d:db:e3:af:7b:d7:c7:1f:7b:4f:1e:d3:d6:b7:d1:b7:79:e5:ed:3d:7f:5e:9f:eb:c6:b4:7d:ef:7b
```

The snippet Im using to base64 decode can be found here https://go.dev/play/p/RBnmwgHIGVV

So, the question is. Does anyone have any idea what algorithm google uses to derive the ID of an uploaded service account key?

Edit: Adding the command used to calculate the fingerprint of my public key: `openssl x509 -in ./public_key.pem -noout -fingerprint`

Comment: For some reason the link to the question I reference was not added to my post. Here is the link to the question: [https://serverfault.com/questions/1030519/google-cloud-how-to-determine-key-id-from-p12](https://serverfault.com/questions/1030519/google-cloud-how-to-determine-key-id-from-p12)

Comment: The Key ID is not base64 encoded. It is hex binary. The Key ID is SHA-1. I did figure it out a few years ago, but I don't remember now. I am curious, what will you do with that knowledge once you find out?

Comment: IIRC the Key ID is the public certificate fingerprint from the DER encoding. Show how you are calculating the fingerprint. I think the issue is with your method.

Comment: @JohnHanley My use case is to integrate with GCP, but my side gets to control the public/private key for security reasons. GCP uses a json file to authenticate their SDK's. This json file is provided when you let GCP generate the key pair. Not on my case, because the public key is uploaded.

So, in order to build my own json file for authentication, I need to derive this ID from the public key.

More info here [https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#sa-impersonation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#sa-impersonation)

Comment: @JohnHanley right now Im just trying to confirm I can derive the ID, Im using the following command in cli: `openssl x509 -in ./public_key.pem -noout -fingerprint`

Comment: 1/2) The definition for the Key ID type is `opaque`. Knowing in advance the Key ID does not help you and I am confused why you are now adding impersonation to the equation. Understanding how RSA works for authorization in GCP is a good idea (I have published articles on this topic), but I would not recommend designing infrastructure that uses unofficial information.

Comment: 2/2) The RSA private key is used to sign, I will also argue that there is very little security improvement if any by generating your own private key. There is an increased security risk if you get it wrong and most developers struggle with encryption, hashing, signing, authorization, and identity. I have been working with Google since the very early days and I have watched many things change. I recommend contacting your sales rep and setting up a meeting with one of their engineers before committing to anything.

Comment: @JohnHanley I converted my public key to DER encoding but the fingerprint remains the same, which makes sense to me because it is the same certificate. 

How exactly should I calculate the fingerprint from the DER encoded certificate?
Im using `openssl x509 -in ./public_key.pem -inform pem -out ./key.der -outform DER` to convert from PEM to DER and then `keytool -printcert -file ./key.der`.

Appreciate the comments regarding the use of the private key.

Comment: PEM is base64 encoded DER usually. DER is the underlying binary format. PKCS1/PKCS8/etc define the objects encoded by DER. There is a difference between an RSA Public Key and an RSA Public Key certificate. Both represent the same thing but are encoded differently. I did my research on this item around 2018. I cannot find my notes that show how I calculated the key ID from the RSA Private Key. They are on a cloud drive somewhere. This weekend, if I have time, I will try to find them.

Comment: Google uses the Key ID to look up the public key. I have written articles on that. However, I have noticed that even when the Key ID is missing from signed JWT assertions, Google can still verify the signature. An example endpoint where the Key ID is used: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs. When you upload an RSA private key to Google Cloud and attach it to a service account, Google creates a similar endpoint with your RSA public key. That is one of the reasons I recommend you do not use your own Key ID algorithm.

Comment: To see the public key that Google uses, open a service account JSON key file and go to the URL defined by the key `client_x509_cert_url`. Grab that certificate and check the fingerprint.

Comment: I did some testing. Go to the URL in my previous comment. Download the matching certificate. When I run this command the fingerprint matches the Key ID: `openssl x509 -in public.cert.pem -fingerprint -sha1` Now the next step is to take the RSA private key and recreate a corresponding public certificate that Google extracts from the RSA private key that you upload.

Comment: You are creating the public certificate incorrectly. The certificate Subject `CN=X` is the string from the service account JSON key `client_id`. The validity is 10 years.

Comment: The validity is exactly 3650 days. There are a few other items to get correct such as `X509v3 Subject Key Identifier` and `X509v3 Authority Key Identifier` and `Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption`. Your command generates `sha256WithRSAEncryption`.

Comment: In summary, I think I was wrong. The Key ID can be generated from the public certificate, but only Google can generate the public certificate. There is one item you cannot duplicate. The "Not before" date in the certificate.

Comment: You also cannot generate the certificate serial number.

Comment: I think the Not Before date is directly related to when the service account was created and not when you added a private key. Regarding the serial number, that might also be a number you can figure out. Still, this is a lot of work to figure something out that will not be useful as far as I can see.

Comment: @JohnHanley I took a closer look at the certs listed in this endpoint `client_x509_cert_url`. Upon inspection I found my public key listed there, the very same file with the very same attributes and encryption.

As you correctly pointed out, if I create the key using google console, the certificate fingerprint in the endpoint matches with the keyID. However that is not the case for public keys that were uploaded, the certificates match but the ID is not just the fingerprint. There is something else happening under the hoods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @john-hanley for his extensive contributions in this thread.

Regarding the question, I found out that the ID for a public key uploaded to a GCP service account is the sha1 of the whole file, not only the certificate.

So, by doing this:

```
publicKeyBytes := []byte(publicKey)
fingerprint := sha1.Sum(publicKeyBytes)
```

The fingerprint matches the ID found on the service account certificate endpoint.

To check this on MacOS this can be used:

```
shasum /path/to/file
```